# Prestashop admin orders controller

Tags: admin, prestashop

I would like to ask about this controller.

In past versions like 1.5 I could find it in admin/tabs and add additional functions.

In 1.6 version I can`t find any admin classes files. So I should edit controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController yes?

```
 elseif(isset($_POST['submitInvoice'])){
            if ($this->tabAccess['edit'] === '1')
            {
                mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_REFIX_.'orders` SET `invoice_number` = \''.$_POST['invoice_number'].'\',`order_date` = \''.$_POST['order_date'].'\', `changed_invoice`=1, `manager`=\''.$cookie->firstname.' '.$cookie->lastname.'\', `changedStatus`= \''.$_POST['changedStatus'].'\' WHERE `id_order` = '.$_GET['id_order']);
            }
        }
```

I add this code to update some values like invoice number or order date. But I can`t to update this. Got same date and number. Is it bad method to update or what?

Comment: Also check `classes/order/...`, maybe you'll find the right file there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should always use modules and hooks to modify PrestaShop logic if possible
- If you need to override a function and there is nor suitable hook, you should use overrides: `override/controllers/admin/AdminOrderController.php`. Contents of this files should look like : `AdminOrderController extends AdminOrderControllerCore`. If you're unsure what I mean, you should try searching for any override classes in overide folder.
- You code is **extremely** unsafe. You should at least use `Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);`.
- You code might not be working because you are writing you values somewhere in the middle of a function, and the Order is an object, which mean that possibly the Order object is saved after you wrote you values to database. When the order object is saved, it overwrites your values